# Why is the drag function not firing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a div that has a class name "active". I want to change its background to green when the user drags the element. I tried the code below but my function is not firing. Here is my code:-

```js
$(function(){
$('.active').ondragend(function(){
   $('.active').css({background: 'green'});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active" draggable="true">Drag Me </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example just use bind.

```js
$(function(){
$('.active').bind('dragend',   function(){

$('.active').css({background: 'green'});

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active" draggable="true">Drag Me </div>
```